# node.js express authorization 'JWT' can't read header

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have a running login system with JWT. On the client side, I am storing the token in a cookie. Works completely stable.

Now, I am trying to store the token in the header without a cookie. I read a lot of entries here, but I don't get it to run.

Post request for login:

```
app.post('login', async (req, res) {
   // check user exists...
   // check password...
   // create token...

   // Sending token:
   res.header('Authorization', userToken);

   // redirect('myroute');
}
```

Get request to open route:

```
app.get('myroute', async (req, res) {

   // try to get header 'Authorization':
   let userToken = req.headers.get('Authorization')   // --> authHeader is undefined

   // logging:
   console.log(req.headers);   // Complete header is logged without ('Authorization', 
                                  userToken) -> but I guess, that´s normal. 

}
```

Where is my mistake? Happy for some help

Comment: Well, without the front-end code related to storing/sending the header, we can't do much..

Comment: Unlike cookies, headers are not automatically copied from a response to a subsequent request. You need front-end code to perform this copy operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're asking, so I refer to Heiko Theißen's comment in general ([node.js express authorization 'JWT' can't read header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71146039/node-js-express-authorization-jwt-cant-read-header#comment125765272_71146039) ). But assuming you send a correct GET request to your backend's "myroute" (must be done on the client side), then you can indeed access the token from there if it was correctly provided in the authorization header. I suspect a syntax error in your attempt to extract the content of the Authorization header. For all I know, you cannot access the authorization header content like this:

```
let userToken = req.headers.get('Authorization');
```

The ways I know to access properties of objects in JavaScript are either

```
let userToken = req.headers.authorization;
```

or

```
let userToken = req.headers["authorization"];
```

So maybe try to access it like that in your code:

```
app.get('myroute', async (req, res) {

   // try to get header 'Authorization':
   let userToken = req.headers.authorization;   // --> should not be undefined if provided correctly by your client

   // logging:
   console.log(req.headers);
}
```